# How does df.groupby('A').agg('min') translate to featuretools?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, featuretools, feature-engineering

Say I have this simple snippet of code. I will group, aggregate, and merge the dataframe:

---

## Using Pandas:

---

#### Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2],
               'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
               'C': [0.3, 0.2, 1.2, -0.5]})
```

df:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   0.3
1   1   2   0.2
2   2   3   1.2
3   2   4   -0.5
```

#### Group and Aggregate

```
df_result = df.groupby('A').agg('min')
df_result.columns =  ['groupby_A(min_'+x+')' for x in df_result.columns]
```

df_result:

```
    groupby_A(min_B)    groupby_A(min_C)
A       
1   1                   0.2
2   3                   -0.5
```

#### Merge

```
df_new = pd.merge(df,df_result,on='A')
df_new
```

df_new:

```
    A   B   C       groupby_A(min_B)    groupby_A(min_C)
0   1   1   0.3     1                   0.2
1   1   2   0.2     1                   0.2
2   2   3   1.2     3                  -0.5
3   2   4   -0.5    3                  -0.5
```

---

## An Attempt using featuretools:

---

```
# ---- Import the Module ----
import featuretools as ft

# ---- Make the Entity Set (the set of all tables) ----
es = ft.EntitySet()

# ---- Make the Entity (the table) ----
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'df', 
                         dataframe = df)


# ---- Do the Deep Feature Synthesis (group, aggregate, and merge the features) ----
feature_matrix, feature_names = ft.dfs(entityset = es, 
                                       target_entity = 'df',
                                       trans_primitives = ['cum_min'])

feature_matrix
```

feature_matrix:

```
        A       B       C       CUM_MIN(A)  CUM_MIN(B)  CUM_MIN(C)
index                       
0       1       1       0.3     1           1           0.3
1       1       2       0.2     1           1           0.2
2       2       3       1.2     1           1           0.2
3       2       4       -0.5    1           1           -0.5
```

---

How does the operation with Pandas translate into featuretools (preferably without adding another table)?

My attempt with featuretools does not give the right output, but I believe the process that I used is somewhat correct.

Comment: kindly add code in question not as  picture ,code from pic cannot be copied

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please paste the code you've tried using `code-formatting` rather than in an image. Could you also explain what you are trying to do and what you have tried? Pasting starting data and expected output helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the recommended way to do it in Featuretools. You do need to create another table to make it work exactly as you want.

```
import featuretools as ft
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'C': [0.3, 0.2, 1.2, -0.5]})

es = ft.EntitySet()

es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="example",
                          index="id",
                          make_index=True,
                          dataframe=df)

es.normalize_entity(new_entity_id="a_entity",
                    base_entity_id="example",
                    index="A")

fm, fl = ft.dfs(target_entity="example",
                entityset=es,
                agg_primitives=["min"])

fm
```

this returns

```
    A  B    C  a_entity.MIN(example.B)  a_entity.MIN(example.C)
id                                                             
0   1  1  0.3                        1                      0.2
1   1  2  0.2                        1                      0.2
2   2  3  1.2                        3                     -0.5
3   2  4 -0.5                        3                     -0.5
```

If you don't want to create an extra table you could try using the `cum_min` primitive which calculate the cumulative after grouping by `A`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'C': [0.3, 0.2, 1.2, -0.5]})

es = ft.EntitySet()

es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="example",
                          index="id",
                          make_index=True,
                          variable_types={
                              "A": ft.variable_types.Id
                          },
                          dataframe=df,)

fm, fl = ft.dfs(target_entity="example",
                entityset=es,
                groupby_trans_primitives=["cum_min"])

fm
```

this returns

```
    B    C  A  CUM_MIN(C) by A  CUM_MIN(B) by A
id                                             
0   1  0.3  1              0.3              1.0
1   2  0.2  1              0.2              1.0
2   3  1.2  2              1.2              3.0
3   4 -0.5  2             -0.5              3.0
```

Comment: Thank you, the first approach gives the results that I am looking for.

Comment: also if the field is a datetime, then we need to sort manually outside,then use first()/last() as min or cum_min is just for Numeric type...